# TFS cannot connect to Sql Server after Server updates

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

Over the weekend, our network admin install updates on our Windows Server 2008 R2 server. After the updates, TFS can no longer connect to Sql Server. Both TFS and Sql Server are on the same box.

I am getting the following error when trying to connect to the `http://mytfsname:8080/tfs/` :

> Team Foundation services are not available from the server. Technical
>   information (for administrator):  The request could not be processed
>   because the application is not configured correctly. No service host
>   is available for the request.

In the TFs Admin Console, I tried to connect with the NETWORK SERVICE account, which results in the following:

> Exception Message: The database is being upgraded to the
>   Tfs2010.SP1.KB2564498.P#5 schema. The database cannot be used until
>   the upgrade is complete. (type DatabaseSchemaException)

Digging into the event logs, there are about 20 errors right after the server was restarted:

> Error in Template (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   9.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\Web\VisualBasic\1033\AdoNetEntityDataModelVB_ASPNET.zip),
>   file (ModelObjectItemVB_ASPNET.vstemplate). Invalid template element
>   (TemplateID) value
>   (Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VSTemplate.ModelObjectItemVB_ASPNET).

Then I start seeing the TFS error:

> TF53010: The following error has occurred in a Team Foundation
>   component or extension: Date (UTC): 2/15/2015 7:00:22 PM Machine:
>   xxxxxxx Application Domain:
>   /LM/W3SVC/8080/ROOT/tfs-1-130685004138949511 Assembly:
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server, Version=10.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxx; v2.0.50727 Service Host: 
>   Process Details:   Process Name: w3wp   Process Id: 6180   Thread Id:
>   7364   Account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
>
> Detailed Message: Application Request Processing Started
>
> Server Version = Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server,
>   Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxx Service
>   Account = NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE Machine Name = XXXXXXX Product
>   ID = xxxxxxxxx License Edition = xxxxx
>
> Exception Message: The database is being upgraded to the
>   Tfs2010.SP1.KB2564498.P#5 schema. The database cannot be used until
>   the upgrade is complete. (type DatabaseSchemaException)

I have tried the following:

- Reinstall TFS (repairing) '
- ReInstall TFS SPI 1 (failed)
- Delete TFS Cache

Comment: If I were you I would consider opening a call with Microsoft if you cannot solve this pretty quickly.

Comment: For what its worth, we restored the server from backup and its up and running. I'll leave the question open to see what may or may not be answered.